# function initialized using let not replaced when accessed by this

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Why are functions initialized with let not replaced when accessed using this?

I have this script:

```
"use strict"
var testfunction1 = function() {
 console.log(false)
}
this.testfunction1 = function() {
 console.log(true)
}
console.log(testfunction1.toString())
console.log(this.testfunction1.toString())

function testfunction2() {
 console.log(false)
}
this.testfunction2 = function() {
 console.log(true)
}
console.log(testfunction2.toString())
console.log(this.testfunction2.toString())

let testfunction3 = function() {
 console.log(false)
}
this.testfunction3 = function() {
 console.log(true)
}
console.log(testfunction3.toString())
console.log(this.testfunction3.toString())
```

It produces this output:

```
function() {
 console.log(true)
}
function() {
 console.log(true)
}
function() {
 console.log(true)
}
function() {
 console.log(true)
}
function() {
 console.log(false)
}
function() {
 console.log(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read it seems that:

> The **let** statement declares a **block scope local variable**, optionally initializing it to a value. - [MDN:let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

And for global function declarations:

> Global function declarations are always represented as own properties of the **global object**. - [ES6:see note at bottom of section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createglobalfunctionbinding)

This would indicate that `let` just creates a locally scoped variable, whereas the other ones are creating it under the `window` object (The global object).

So the standard declarations are being overwritten by the `this` prefixed ones, whereas the `let` based one is in the local scope and is used over that declared on the current context.

Comment: Your quote about `var` does not apply to this.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 38 gives "true" at every request. In the Mozilla documentation, *let* should act just as *var* if not inserted in a block.

But it appears the way that *let* is implemented in Firefox 38 is not correct regarding to the last specifications.

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/10/14/breaking-changes-let-const-firefox-nightly-44/

Comment: what firefox version are you using? let does not assign to the global object in 45. anyway, you should check what the standard says, not how browsers implement newly-standardized features. behavior may still be in flux.

Comment: Firefox ESR 38.4.0. I just read Mozilla documentation and tested it : it is consistant. If you know more "standard" place than MDN, I'm interested.

Comment: Let is an ES2015 feature. 38 was released before ES2015 spec was finalized. And even after that browsers still need some time to catch up to the spec. Here's a recent change: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/10/14/breaking-changes-let-const-firefox-nightly-44/